# Audio Unit file recording with aurioTouch - AudioStreamBasicDescription configuration issue?

Tags: ios, core-audio, audio-recording, audiounit

I've started down the path on learning Audio Unit with aurioTouch.  After a few days of learning Audio Unit, I'm still feeling a bit lost and I think I'm missing something very obvious.

Full source can be view at: http://pastebin.com/LXLYDEhy

Also listed the partial source down here

**In my performRender callback, I've changed the code to**

```
static OSStatus performRender (void                         *inRefCon,
                           AudioUnitRenderActionFlags   *ioActionFlags,
                           const AudioTimeStamp         *inTimeStamp,
                           UInt32                       inBusNumber,
                           UInt32                       inNumberFrames,
                           AudioBufferList              *ioData) {

OSStatus err = noErr;
AudioController *audioController = (__bridge AudioController *)inRefCon;  
AudioBufferList bufferList;
bufferList.mNumberBuffers = 1;
bufferList.mBuffers[0].mData = NULL;
OSStatus status;
status = AudioUnitRender(cd.rioUnit,
                         ioActionFlags,
                         inTimeStamp,
                         inBusNumber,
                         inNumberFrames,
                         &bufferList); // bufferList.mBuffers[0].mData is null
status = ExtAudioFileWriteAsync(audioController.extAudioFileRef, bufferList.mNumberBuffers, &bufferList);
}
```

**The audio units are setup like this**

```
- (AudioStreamBasicDescription)getAudioDescription {
AudioStreamBasicDescription audioDescription = {0};
audioDescription.mFormatID          = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
audioDescription.mFormatFlags       = kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked | kAudioFormatFlagsNativeEndian;
audioDescription.mChannelsPerFrame  = 1;
audioDescription.mBytesPerPacket    = sizeof(SInt16)*audioDescription.mChannelsPerFrame;
audioDescription.mFramesPerPacket   = 1;
audioDescription.mBytesPerFrame     = sizeof(SInt16)*audioDescription.mChannelsPerFrame;
audioDescription.mBitsPerChannel    = 8 * sizeof(SInt16);
audioDescription.mSampleRate        = 44100.0;
return audioDescription;
}


- (void)setupIOUnit
{
try {
    // Create a new instance of AURemoteIO

    AudioComponentDescription desc;
    desc.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Output;
    desc.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO;
    desc.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;
    desc.componentFlags = 0;
    desc.componentFlagsMask = 0;

    AudioComponent comp = AudioComponentFindNext(NULL, &desc);
    XThrowIfError(AudioComponentInstanceNew(comp, &_rioUnit), "couldn't create a new instance of AURemoteIO");

    //  Enable input and output on AURemoteIO
    //  Input is enabled on the input scope of the input element
    //  Output is enabled on the output scope of the output element

    UInt32 one = 1;
    XThrowIfError(AudioUnitSetProperty(_rioUnit, kAudioOutputUnitProperty_EnableIO, kAudioUnitScope_Input, 1, &one, sizeof(one)), "could not enable input on AURemoteIO");
    XThrowIfError(AudioUnitSetProperty(_rioUnit, kAudioOutputUnitProperty_EnableIO, kAudioUnitScope_Output, 0, &one, sizeof(one)), "could not enable output on AURemoteIO");

    // Explicitly set the input and output client formats
    // sample rate = 44100, num channels = 1, format = 32 bit floating point

    CAStreamBasicDescription ioFormat = CAStreamBasicDescription(44100, 1, CAStreamBasicDescription::kPCMFormatFloat32, false);
//        AudioStreamBasicDescription audioFormat = [self getAudioDescription];
    XThrowIfError(AudioUnitSetProperty(_rioUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, kAudioUnitScope_Output, 1, &ioFormat, sizeof(ioFormat)), "couldn't set the input client format on AURemoteIO");
    XThrowIfError(AudioUnitSetProperty(_rioUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, kAudioUnitScope_Input, 0, &ioFormat, sizeof(ioFormat)), "couldn't set the output client format on AURemoteIO");

    // Set the MaximumFramesPerSlice property. This property is used to describe to an audio unit the maximum number
    // of samples it will be asked to produce on any single given call to AudioUnitRender
    UInt32 maxFramesPerSlice = 4096;
    XThrowIfError(AudioUnitSetProperty(_rioUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_MaximumFramesPerSlice, kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0, &maxFramesPerSlice, sizeof(UInt32)), "couldn't set max frames per slice on AURemoteIO");

    // Get the property value back from AURemoteIO. We are going to use this value to allocate buffers accordingly
    UInt32 propSize = sizeof(UInt32);
    XThrowIfError(AudioUnitGetProperty(_rioUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_MaximumFramesPerSlice, kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0, &maxFramesPerSlice, &propSize), "couldn't get max frames per slice on AURemoteIO");

    _bufferManager = new BufferManager(maxFramesPerSlice);
    _dcRejectionFilter = new DCRejectionFilter;

    // We need references to certain data in the render callback
    // This simple struct is used to hold that information

    cd.rioUnit = _rioUnit;
    cd.bufferManager = _bufferManager;
    cd.dcRejectionFilter = _dcRejectionFilter;
    cd.muteAudio = &_muteAudio;
    cd.audioChainIsBeingReconstructed = &_audioChainIsBeingReconstructed;

    AURenderCallbackStruct renderCallback;
    renderCallback.inputProc = performRender;
    renderCallback.inputProcRefCon = self;

    XThrowIfError(AudioUnitSetProperty(_rioUnit, kAudioOutputUnitProperty_SetInputCallback, kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0, &renderCallback, sizeof(renderCallback)), "couldn't set render callback on AURemoteIO");


    // Initialize the AURemoteIO instance
    XThrowIfError(AudioUnitInitialize(_rioUnit), "couldn't initialize AURemoteIO instance");
}

catch (CAXException &e) {
    NSLog(@"Error returned from setupIOUnit: %d: %s", (int)e.mError, e.mOperation);
}
catch (...) {
    NSLog(@"Unknown error returned from setupIOUnit");
}

return;
}
```

Full source can be view at: http://pastebin.com/LXLYDEhy

Comment: What is the question/problem?  You gave us code, but no description of what error you're hitting

Comment: Thanks jn_pdx.  The problem is that this produce files that only contain the header but with no audio data.  The files are about 58 bytes each.  But I receive all valid OSStatus of 0 for every operation.

Answer (score 0):

Your code generally looks good from glancing at it, but there's at least one significant issue:  instead of allocating space for the data to be copied into the buffers, you are explicitly setting them to `NULL`.  Instead, you should allocate space and then copy it in with `AudioUnitRender`

Example code:

```
AudioBufferList *bufferList;
bufferList = (AudioBufferList *)malloc(sizeof(AudioBufferList) + sizeof(AudioBuffer));
bufferList->mNumberBuffers = 1;
bufferList->mBuffers[0].mNumberChannels = 1;
bufferList->mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize = 1024 * 4;
bufferList->mBuffers[0].mData = calloc(1024, 4);
```

(Note that you may need to adjust the allocation sizes to fit your stream type, size, etc -- the above is just example code, but it addresses your main issue.

Comment: Hi jn_pdx.  That didn't work but I have abandon the idea of using this.  Instead my real issue that I was trying to solve was in this thread.  I'm getting close but it's not working yet.  Do you think you can help?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27893428/recording-audio-with-audio-unit-with-files-segmented-in-x-number-of-seconds-each/27957974#27957974